# To keep a particular menu open on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi iam working on my shopify website. what iam trying to do is to keep a particular dropdown menu open on page load.The drop down menu uses class "open" to open a drop down menu on page load.here is my website url"https://malpassbutchery.co.uk/"

```js
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $('.main-nav .nav-item.drop-norm').addClass('open');
});
```

This is the code i have tried but its not working

Comment: Why not hardcode the class to the markup?

Comment: jQuery(window).load(function() {
    $('li:first-child').addClass('open');
});

Comment: i have done it, its comming dynamic that is why

Comment: We need a [mcve] here in the post, we're not going to investigate your entire web site.

Comment: $('.main-nav .nav-item.drop-norm').addClass('open'); this you select multiple element, so it does not work.